# AngularJS ng-click not firing from anchor click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an AngularJS link that is not firing, so that when the item is clicked, nothing happens. The click event only has one line of code, that works in other parts of the website:

```
// Load Add Job Template
dashboard.loadAddJob = function() {
    dashboard.global.template = "templates/AddJob.html";
}
```

And the click element is a simple link:

```
<a ng-click="loadAddJob()">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i><br />
    Add <br />Job
</a>
```

Everything else works on the page so I know the controller and app are both declared correctly. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: what is dashboard? Is dashboard your this instance(controller As syntax)?

Comment: can u share more code on plunker?

Comment: You should know by now to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your function should be,

```
$scope.loadAddJob = function() {
    dashboard.global.template = "templates/AddJob.html";
}
```

if you are using Controller as syntax, the HTML should be changed to,

```
<a ng-click="dashboard.loadAddJob()">
```

Comment: Or they could be using the `controllerAs` syntax in which case they'd need to change `ng-click="dashboard.loadAddJob()"`

Comment: then it should be <a ng-click="dashboard.loadAddJob()">

Comment: I've missed it out but I have a line in my code that renames the $scope for ease `var dashboard = this` - putting dashboard at the start of the function in the ng-click did fix the issue though, thanks!